# Should my in-browser data models be singletons?

Tags: reactjs, model, eventemitter

I am doing a React app and I want to do my in memory data models with es6 modules and EventEmitter. Wondering if it is recommended to use a singleton.

Also I heard that [this event emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wolfy87-eventemitter) is the one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes! Models in a module based front end should be singletons!
Otherwise their data is not persistent across the various imports!